# debugging with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer

I have some code that I thought I had written so that it would play nice on IE.  But apparently it does not.  I use IE8 for my testing and get quite frustrated with the built-in debugging 'tool'.  I found that firebug has a javascript tool that debugs for IE but I have to click it for every page, wait for it to load and then test my script.  Is there a way to make IE ALWAYS load the firebug .js file?  I tried searching for way to set up a custom header file for my IE installation but was unsuccessful.

Is there another tool out there that would be better/easier to use?  Another way to test scripts for IE compatibility?

Comment: Welcome to the game. Working with different browsers is a fickle pursuit that will consume your life if you let it. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

IE7 and 8 provided the [IE developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en). This is similar to firebug for DOM inspection, script debugging and style tracing.

**Edit:**

For IE 8, the toolbar is already packaged with the browser:

> The Developer Toolbar is not compatible with Internet Explorer 8.  Please use the developer tools included with Internet Explorer 8.  Press F12 or click the 'Developer Tools' entry in the Tools menu to begin using the tool.  [Click here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=111673) for more information on IE8 Developer Tools.

Comment: I am a big Firebug user and I actually slightly prefer the new IE Developer toolbar for IE8

Comment: @John, except for some dynamicism issues, I prefer webkit's developer tools over both, but that's just me.

Comment: I don't see the developer toolbar for ie8... only for ie6 and ie7.  Is there an easy way to have both ie7 and ie8 installed on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Visual Studio and attach to the process in question, then just debug in VS. Pretty good debugging tools, and lets you debug IE6 as well.

Comment: I looked at visual studio and found the trial downloads but the only pricing information I could find suggested that I would have to pay 1k+ to keep this as a long-term solution.  Is there a way to get this at a reasonable price?

Comment: Visual Web Developer Express does all that, and is free: http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/#2010-Visual-Web-Developer

Answer (score 0):

Try my [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/), which is a logging library that works in every major browser, including IE 5 and later.